# Column of dataframe titled "patientid" with input "abcd12345", need to remove the letters from the column so patientID looks like "12345"?

Tags: python

I have inported an excel sheet with multiple columns and rows. One of the columns is titled `PatientID` and I need to identify just the numbers in each cell and replace the current inputs. Basically need to go from this:

```
PatientID
abc12312
adb12312
adfad12312
sfa123124
asd1241123
adsf13123
```

to

```
PatientID
12312
12312
12312
123124
1241123
13123
```

Please help! Using Jupyter notebook. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def func(value):
    return re.sub("[^0-9]", "", value)

# sample data for patient id column
data = ["abc12312" ,"adb12312" ,"adfad12312" ,"sfa123124" ,"asd1241123", "adsf13123"]

# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['PatientID'])

#make the required change by removing alphabets from the alphanumeric value
df['PatientID'] =df['PatientID'].apply(lambda x:func(x))

print(df)
```